# how to display current time of the system on window created by cv2.imshow()

Tags: datetime, user-interface, opencv, python

I am trying to display the current time of the system on window created by cv2.imshow() with some properties included. I have searched the internet but couldn't find what I want. All I want is to see current time on my window. Maybe it is possible through setting some kind of flag or property in window property, but I am not able to find it anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Displaying the time on a window involves two things:

1. Obtaining the time from the system
2. Displaying the time as a text

The following Python code illustrates both these steps:

```
import cv2

#--- to obtain time ---
from time import strftime

#--- read the image ---
x = r'C:\Users\Jackson\Desktop\Stack\Homography\Spartacus.jpg'
img = cv2.imread(x, 1)
    
#--- Position the time at (10, 70) coordinate with certain font style, size and color ---
cv2.putText(img, strftime("%H:%M:%S"), (10,70), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2,(0,255,0),2,cv2.LINE_AA)
cv2.imshow('img', img)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**Result**

[image]

The code above only displays the time. However, if you want to display the date print the following as text:

```
strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

[image]

### EDIT:

This is in response to have a light color in the background. You can use `cv2.rectangle()` to have a rectangular region of any color. You can decide the size, color, thickness and whether it has to be filled or not.

The following will draw a filled white rectangle of dimension (510 x 128) and at location x = 384 and y = 50:

```
cv2.rectangle(img, (384, 50), (510, 128), (255, 255, 255), -1)
```

**Note:** Make sure you draw the rectangle and then put the date to make sure the date is placed above the rectangular region.

Comment: thank you, you helped me a lot. I have one more thing to ask, actually I am displaying a camera frame in real time and window has some borders that I don't need at all. If you look at [this](https://habrastorage.org/webt/c1/dz/o4/c1dzo4val_jkd3or4auca5yltya.jpeg) window of that frame, you can see boders like green arrows at the top, coordinates in the bottom and paddings for both sides. Is it possible get rid of of these? It should be just like the image you provided above.

Comment: I just found out that `cv2.namedWindow(" ", cv2.WINDOW_GUI_NORMAL)` does the job but it still keeps the title bar

Comment: @voo_doo Can you share the image in the question? Another thing, do you want the time to be displayed on the image or on the title of the window?

Comment: It'd be better if that image is shared via link only for my personal reasons. And the time should be displayed on the image. here should be no title bar at all.

Comment: and I should put some light color background in order for time to be visible clearly

Comment: @voo_doo I have added more details. Feel free to reach out